# Need help in quantitatively modeling solubility of carbon dioxide in beer.

Tags: physics, 3d, mathematical-modeling, chemistry

I'm trying to model a 3D surface which reflects the solubility of $CO_2$ in beer. An empirically derived chart is available [at this link](https://www.zahmnagel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Zahm-Nagel-CO2-in-Beer-Chart.pdf).

Solubility is empirically related to the pressure of $CO_2$ in the space above the beer and to temperature. Solubility is directly and linearly related to the pressure (Henry's Law). Solubility is exponentially related to the temperature of the beer (Van't Hoff).

I intend to use python's scipy's curve_fit (with a custom function) to minimize the least-squares difference between my model and the data in the chart.

I am assuming the following relationships between solubility, pressure, and temperature:

With respect to pressure,

$$solubility(pressure) = m \times pressure + b$$

With respect to temperature,

$$solubility(temperature) = C+A\times e^{(B\times temperature)}$$

My question is this: what should my custom estimating function look like?
$$solubility(pressure,temperature) = ???$$

Comment: I suppose $solubility=c_1 p+c_2+(c_3 p+c_4)\exp {BT}$ will satisfy both laws

Comment: I understand the c1p+c2 terms, but how does pressure get introduced in the third term (c3p+c4)?

Comment: For any constant $T$ solubility must satisfy to linear pressure law: $sol=mp+m$. But $m$ and $b$ can depend on temperature. $sol=m(T)p+b(T)$. For any constant $p$ solubility must satisfy exponential temperature law, then $sol=C+A\exp(BT)$. Where $C$, $A$, $B$ can depend on $p$.
$C(p)+A(p)\exp(B(p)T)=m(T)p+b(T)$ for any $p$, $T$.

Comment: For left hand side to be linear by $p$ at constant $T$ one should state that $C(p)$ and $A(p)$ are linear and $B(p)$ is constant.

Comment: Perfect. Excellent explanation. I've constructed a model using these equations in scipy,optimize.curve_fit and am able to generate a surface that differs from the reference data to the third significant digit. Just what I was looking for.